# Incorrect classnames in Material UI with styled components inside react frame

Tags: reactjs, iframe, material-ui, styled-components

I am using `react-frame-component` to load a custom component I created which is using `material ui` and `styled-components`.

The custom component I created is irrelevant but contains the following relevant code:

```
const StyledCardHeader = styled(({ isRTL, ...rest }) => (
  <CardHeader {...rest} />
))`
  ${({ theme, isRTL }) => `
    & .MuiCardHeader-title {
      margin-right:${isRTL ? 0 : theme.spacing(2)}px;
      margin-left:  ${isRTL ? theme.spacing(2) : 0}px;
    }
`};
`;
```

When it renders, the actual classname becomes something else than I expect: `MuiCardHeader-title-34` (it adds the 34 as suffix - random number).

Therefore, my custom styled is not being applied.

[image]

Here's a sandbox of the above:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-field-ui82v

Answer (score 1):

You can look into [overriding](https://material-ui.com/api/card-header/#css) the MUI CardHeader CSS based off of the docs.

```
<CardHeader
  {...rest}
  classes={{
    title: makeStyles({
      customTitleMargin: {
        marginRight: `${isRTL ? 0 : theme.spacing(2)}px`,
        marginLeft: `${isRTL ? theme.spacing(2) : 0}px`,
      }
    })().customTitleMargin
  }}
/>
```

I did not want to mess with your code too much so in my example, I just plugged in the `makeStyles` export from `@material-ui/styles`, but the logic of future implementations is similar in that you should just override the MUI component itself.

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-joliot-5mf8n?file=/src/Card.js

Comment: Although it does work, the way I did it is the way to override material ui css with styled components, it can be seen here: https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#deeper-elements-2

My way also work when it's not encapsulated, just doesnt work in the encapsulation because the classes have suffixes.